# Select data with calculation in same data table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My Table is

```
itemcode  in out  sum value   datetime     PP   
-------|---|---|-----------|-----------|---------   
A1234  | 1 | 0 | 100       |04/03/2009 | E01  
A1234  | 0 | 1 | -100      |05/03/2009 | E01    
A1234  | 1 | 0 | 100       |06/03/2009 | E01   
A1234  | 0 | 1 | -100      |07/03/2009 | E01   
A1234  | 1 | 0 | 100       |08/03/2009 | E01   
A1234  | 9 | 0 | 900       |09/03/2009 | S01  
A1234  | 0 | 3 | -300      |10/03/2009 | S01  
A1234  | 8 | 0 | 800       |11/03/2009 | S01 
A1235  | 9 | 0 | 900       |12/03/2009 | E01   
A1235  | 0 | 2 | -200      |13/03/2009 | E01  
A1235  | 0 | 3 | -300      |14/03/2009 | E01  
A1235  | 8 | 0 | 800       |15/03/2009 | S01
```

Result would be:

```
itemcode   Remain   sum value   datetime    PP

---------|--------|-----------|-----------|----
A1234    | 1      | 100       |08/03/2009 | E01
A1234    | 6      | 600       |09/03/2009 | S01
A1234    | 8      | 800       |11/03/2009 | S01
A1235    | 4      | 400       |12/03/2009 | E01
A1235    | 8      | 800       |15/03/2009 | S01
```

How to select such data and calculate how many stock remaining, group by same itemcode and pp,
list out in different in stock date

Comment: Your expected result doesn't make any sense. What are you grouping by? There is no significant grouping there.

Comment: i don't understand why is not make sense? i need to find out how many stock remaining in each in stock date. group by same item code and same pp code, and no need to show if the remain stock is 0

Comment: If you are grouping by the same itemcode and pp code, wouldn't your rows 2 and 3 be combined together? Also, which dates are 'in stock dates' why did you use 07/03 for the first row?

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do this is use the SUM() function to sum the in column, as well as the out column, and subtract them to get the value that is in stock. Once you've done that, you can use the GROUP BY clause to group the columns you want. Intuitively, it works pretty closely to what you described.

You'll also have to do something with the datecolumn, and it seems that you want to produce the latest date in each group, so I've also selected the max date for that reason.

You didn't list the column names in your question, so I'm going on a limb here:

```
SELECT itemcode, (SUM(inColumn) - SUM(outColumn)) AS inStock, SUM(value) AS value, MAX(dateColumn) AS latestDate, pp
FROM myTable
GROUP BY itemcode, pp;
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec18313/1).

Comment: this concept is sth wrong, if the remain stock is more than the last in stock date?you just find out the last date is not correct.

Comment: Your expected result set in the question is a little confusing. I'm not sure what you're grouping by. Can you explain what's different about rows 2 and 3 in your result set? Why aren't they grouped together? It's the same pp and same itemcode, so shouldn't they be combined?

Comment: because the in stock date was different, so it can't be group.

Comment: All dates are different, so what could be grouped?

Comment: In the first row, you have the date '07/03' but on that date in the original table it is an out date, with a value of -100, so it doesn't match. I'm just having a hard time understanding what you're actually looking for.

Comment: @hugolui this returns an almost identical result set to yours. The only difference is that rows 2 and 3 of your result set are combined into 1, as you stated you wanted to do, because you want to group by itemcode and ppcode.

Comment: Sorry for typing mistake, the first row is 08/03/2009.